# How to call a different function base on a different drop down selection in javascript,

Tags: javascript, function

the problem is that I want to use a different calculation base on a different selection

```
function Rec(form) {
  form.recanswer.value =
    form.feet.value *
    (form.recanswer.value =
      form.reclength.value * form.recheight.value * 2 +
      form.recheight.value * form.recwidth.value * 2 +
      form.reclength.value * form.recwidth.value);
}
```

I call this function above when I make the selection in the select form below

```
<select name="feet" size="4" id="feet" autofocus>
    <option class="box" value="4.50" selected="selected">Used Panel</option>
    <option class="box" value="5.75">3" New Panel</option> 
    <option class="box" value="6.75">4" New Panel</option>
 </select>
```

---

```
function Rec(form2) {
  form2.recanswer2.value =
    form2.feet.value *
    (form2.recanswer.value =
      form2.reclength.value * form2.recheight.value * form2.recwidth.value);
}
```

My problem is that I want to use a different function call whenever I select Installation in the select form

```
<select name="feet" size="4" id="feet" autofocus>
    <option class="box" value="250">Installation</option>
</select>
```

base on this event

```
<input type="button" value="Get Quote" onclick="Rec(this.form)" />
```

the output value will display here
Quote: $

```
<input name="recanswer" type="text" size="5" />
```

Comment: Consider naming the two functions differently, using one event listener for both buttons, and using an if statement to determine which `Rec` function is called.

Comment: Can you please show me how should I do it?